# Jest with Selenium 4 - compatibility issue with ES6: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

[update at the bottom]

I just installed today jest in my small project, in which I use Selenium (with Javascript) to do some tests on a simple project.

Since Selenium 4 does only support ES6 now, I have to use modules. But Jest seems to not like them, so I searched on stackoverflow for some solutions, and this is what I got until now.

Aim: test a simple API call that calls a function to transform the result in an array.

What happens: jest throws the error `ReferenceError: require is not defined` at line 5 of `mockApi.test.js`: `jest.mock('axios')`

files:

`backendCalls.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

// returns an object for every coach, 
// a coach has firstName, lastName and some other properties
export async function getCoachesList(area) {
  let res = await axios
    .get('localhost:8080/coaches.json')
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.toJSON())
    })

  // this function simply takes the result - an object containing 5 objects - 
  // and put them in an array with a for loop
  return putObjInArray(res, area)
}
```

this is the test file:

`mockApi.test.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'
import * as beCalls from '../utils/backendCalls.js'
import { expect, jest, test } from '@jest/globals'

jest.mock('axios')

test('should fetch users', () => {
  const coaches = [
    { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Kelso' },
    { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  ]
  const resp = { data: coaches }
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp)

  getCoachesList().then(data => expect(data).toEqual(coaches))
})
```

and finally this is the jest config file:

`jest.config.js`

```
export default {
  jest: {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transform: {},
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!variables/.*)'],
  },
}
```

Everything super simple - in my `package.json` I have this line:

```
"scripts": {
    "jestTests": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
    [...]  // other stuff
}
```

and my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "chai": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.7.0"
  }
```

It should run smoothly, but when I do

`npm run jestTests`

it throws an error, saying `ReferenceError: require is not defined` at line 5 of `mockApi.test.js`: `jest.mock('axios')`

Avoiding the fact I can't believe that in 2023 the ES6 is still not fully implemented (it has been made 10 years ago), what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

**UPDATE:**
I've tried converting everything in a PRE-ES6 version (e.g. using `require` instead of `import`) and now it works.
Unfortunately, Selenium now only supports the ES6 syntax.

So, to be clear, **is it right that Jest is NOT compatible with Selenium**?